# C#: Data Grid View Advanced Operations

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am developing a windows form application in C#. I have a datagridview on windows form.
This datagridview is poupulated dynamically, through some text file.
Now what i want to achieve the following functionaity

1) Normally, when user clicks on my datagridview then the respected cell is selceted i want to remove this functionality.i.e if user click anywhere on my datagridview then noting will happens

2) Along with this datagridview i also have a menu strip in my form, the second thing which i want to achieve is that when user click on a specific button (say B) then my mouse cursor changes to plus shape(+) and it allows user to draw a box on my datagridview. On the basis of which i later perform some calculation.

Since i am new to .net thats why i don't know how to acheive this. So reference to some tutorial will also work.

Comment: What do you mean by **draw a box** , intend to achieve what please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first part of the question can be done by

```
dataGridView1.Enabled = false;
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
```

Can you elaborate a bit more on the second

Comment: Its a UI, business logic is developed in c++. This app gets a .txt file then copy all lines in a array & then display those lines in above mentioned datagridview in such a way that a single line is displayed in a single row and each cell of a row contains a single char. The next step is to allow user to draw a box on that DGV e.g Lets assume there is a phone number written somewhere in our text file. Now my program display all file contents in DGV, and then user draws a box at phone number which specifies start and end of phone no and so on . . .

Comment: So do you mean reading from the co-ordinates confined by the box user draws ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the first thing is that how to code which enables user to draw a box.

Comment: Won't allowing **multi select** in the grid server your purpose, because i think drawing the box would involve overriding the paint method which is not going to be an easy task

Answer (score 0):

For the 1 problem you have said, write the following line of code in Selected index changed event `grid.Selectedindex=-1;`